keytheorems - Different "theorems" with the same number formatting
The code given at the end of this post prints the following output.
Atest 1. Bla, bla, bla, ... 
Atest 2. Bla, bla, bla, ... 
Btest 1.1.3. Bla, bla, bla, ...    <-- KO
Atest 4. Bla, bla, bla, ...        
Ctest 1.1.5. Bla, bla, bla, ...    <-- KO
Dtest 1.1.6. Bla, bla, bla, ...    <-- KO

I fail in the automation of my process to obtain:
Atest 1. Bla, bla, bla, ... 
Atest 2. Bla, bla, bla, ... 
Btest 3. Bla, bla, bla, ...    <-- WANTED    
Atest 4. Bla, bla, bla, ...     
Ctest 5. Bla, bla, bla, ...    <-- WANTED
Dtest 6. Bla, bla, bla, ...    <-- WANTED

My M(not)WE.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keytheorems}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \__g_projetmbc_test_seq

\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \__g_projetmbc_test_seq {
  Atest,
  Btest,
  Ctest,
  Dtest
}

\seq_map_inline:Nn \__g_projetmbc_test_seq {
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { Atest } {
    \newkeytheorem{#1}[
      name       = #1,
      within     = subsection,
    ]
  } {
    \newkeytheorem{#1}[
      name       = #1,
      numberlike = Atest
    ]
  }
}

\renewcommand{\theAtest}{\arabic{Atest}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

  
\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{Atest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Atest}

\begin{Atest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Atest}

\begin{Btest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Btest}

\begin{Atest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Atest}

\begin{Ctest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Ctest}

\begin{Dtest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Dtest}

\end{document}


Each theorem has its own counter representation \the<name>. So you need to redefine this representation for every theorem. Here just add
\cs_set:cpn { the #1 } { \arabic{#1} }

for each item in the sequence. Full example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keytheorems}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \__g_projetmbc_test_seq

\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \__g_projetmbc_test_seq {
  Atest,
  Btest,
  Ctest,
  Dtest
}

\seq_map_inline:Nn \__g_projetmbc_test_seq {
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { Atest } {
    \newkeytheorem{#1}[
      name       = #1,
      within     = subsection,
    ]
  } {
    \newkeytheorem{#1}[
      name       = #1,
      numberlike = Atest
    ]
  }
\cs_set:cpn { the #1 } { \arabic{#1} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

  
\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{Atest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Atest}

\begin{Atest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Atest}

\begin{Btest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Btest}

\begin{Atest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Atest}

\begin{Ctest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Ctest}

\begin{Dtest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Dtest}

\subsection{Another Subsection}

\begin{Atest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Atest}

\begin{Atest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Atest}

\begin{Btest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Btest}

\begin{Atest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Atest}

\begin{Ctest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Ctest}

\begin{Dtest}
   Bla, bla, bla, ...
\end{Dtest}

\end{document}



Thanks a lot for the \cs_set:cpn that I fail to see in the interface3 document.

Can you confirm that the parameter part of cpn is considered empty in \cs_set:cpn { the #1 } { \arabic{#1} }?

@projetmbc Yes that’s correct
